# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $image = DB::select(`produits.id`, `produits.name`, `categories.name`, `produits.description`, `produits.volume`, `produits.poids`, `users.name`, `users.numtel`)
        ->from(`produits`)
        ->from(`users`)
        ->from(`categories`)
        ->where(`produits.category_id`, `=`, `categories.id`)
        ->where(`users.id`, `=`, `produits.user_id`)
        ->where(`produits.description`, `=`, [$search])
        ->get();


    return view('home', ['produits' => $image]);
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue? If so **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There a quite a few issues with the code you've shown above.

Firstly, use single or double quotes(`'` or `"`) not back ticks (**`**).

---

When calling `select()` straight from the `DB` facade is going to call the `select()` method on `Connection` which is different to the `select()` method from the `Builder` class. The select on the `Connection` instance is essentially for performing raw queries.

To get the `Builder` instance you can either start your chain with `query()` or  `table()` (which is essentially the `from()` method) e.g.

```
DB::table('table_name)
```

or

```
DB::query()->from('table_name')
```

---

AFAIK, you can't specify multiple tables with the query builder so you will need to join the tables instead.

---

Ultimately, you query should look something like:

```
DB::table('produits')
    ->select('produits.id', 'produits.name', 'categories.name', 'produits.description', 'produits.volume', 'produits.poids', 'users.name', 'users.numtel')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'produits.user_id')
    ->join('categories', 'produits.category_id', 'categories.id')
    ->where('produits.description', $search)
    ->get();
```